# Any Machine Learning Toolbox in Matlab that are Computationally Effective?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

I am new to Machine Learning. I had learnt about ANN, SVR and ANN optmised with GA and PSO, but I realised that ANN involving long run time due to high computational effort. Is there any other machine learning toolbox in Matlab that perform faster than SVR?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i don't know a lot on Matlab toolbox, but I can maybe help you on machine learning on a more general way. Do you need only a faster algorithm or better performing overall ?

Kind of a beginner too, but i'd say it really depends if :

- it's a regression, classification or clustering task.
- The complexity of the goal you want to achieve.
- The Dataset you have.

I came across a microsoft post to help you chose your algorithm that is quite cool as a starting point, you should take a look, there is a graph that answers your question : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/algorithm-choice

Some other will have better advices than me but heh that's a start.

Good luck,
Marc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would like to do regression, and I realised that ANN is computationally ineffective. Would seek for other alternatives.  :)